# Visual Studio mscorlib classes source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mscorlib

In NetBeans using Java I can open java.lang.String class and I see that class source code. If I try to open System.String class in VisualStudio I see methods signatures only. 
Is it possible to install VisualStudio plug-in or something like that to open mscorlib classes source code pressing F12?

Thanks for your answers.
I've found the best solution for me: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx (not worth posting as an answer, given that it's just a link...)

Comment: Note, that many of core classes partially implemented in native code (`MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)`).

Answer (score 5):

What you want is at "Microsoft Reference Source Code Center", with the .NET Library sources at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/.

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for can be achieved by using [dot peek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) from [Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com).

Jetbrains offer some other cool software too, like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html?topRS) which can have dot peek included and you can navigate to the decompiled sources.

[image]

You can get the actual source code, not decompiled, from the symbol files which is the option beneath the one I have highlighted, you would need to do what the other answer says by setting up your symbol server.

**UPDATE: See Bruno Brants answer.**

Answer (score 4):

While the previous answers are good, you have a better option now: [Microsoft has open-sourced .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/11/12/net-core-is-open-source.aspx), and not only that, all of it is available [at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet).

Also, it's now possible to configure Visual Studio to check referencesource.microsoft.com while debugging.